# Create sphere in d dimensions using (d+1) points (or less)

Tags: multidimensional-array, geometry, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

Say I have N points in D-dimensional space; where N can be a number from 4 up to D+1.

I want to create the smallest possible sphere defined by these N points, or in other words, a minimal sphere which contains all N points (it passes exactly through all of them).

The variables of the solution are it's center and radius.

I'm bad with matrices, and I guess this problem requires them?

Comment: Do you want the sphere of minimum radius, the sphere passing exactly through each of the points, or something else?

Comment: A (possibly, but not necessarily minimal) sphere passing exactly through each of the points. Sorry for the ambiguity. I'll edit the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're looking for a (minimal) [circumsphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_sphere) for your points `x`. As you've suggested, such an object can be calculated via a bit of linear algebra.

Given a set of `m` points `x` in `n` dimensions `(m <= n+1)`, such that:

```
x = [x_11, x_12, ..., x_1n]
    [x_21, x_22, ..., x_2n]
    .
    .
    .
    [x_m1, x_m2, ..., x_mn]
```

It's possible to write down the equations for a common sphere of radius `R`, centred at `X = [X_1,X_2,...,X_n]` that passes through each of the points in `x`:

```
(x_11 - X_1)^2 + (x_12 - X_2)^2 + ... + (x_1n - X_n)^2 = R^2      (1)
(x_21 - X_1)^2 + (x_22 - X_2)^2 + ... + (x_2n - X_n)^2 = R^2      (2)
.
.
.
(x_m1 - X_1)^2 + (x_m2 - X_2)^2 + ... + (x_mn - X_n)^2 = R^2      (m)
```

Expanding the quadratic terms in each equation, subtracting `(1)` from equations `(2)--(m)`, and doing a little manipulation, leads to a set of linear equations for the centre `X`:

```
M * X = B
```

where:

```
M = [x_11-x_21, x_12-x_22, ..., x_1n-x_2n]
    .
    .
    .
    [x_11-x_m1, x_12-x_m2, ..., x_1n-x_mn]

B = [x_11^2-x_21^2 + x_12^2-x_22^2 + ... + x_1n^2-x_2n^2] * (1/2)
    .
    .
    .
    [x_11^2-x_m1^2 + x_12^2-x_m2^2 + ... + x_1n^2-x_mn^2] * (1/2)
```

Note that `M` is an `(m-1) x n` matrix, while `B` is an `(m-1) x 1` vector.

Clearly, when `m = n+1`, the matrix is square, and there is a unique solution for the centre `X`, fully describing the circumsphere associated with the points `x`. (The radius can be obtained as the distance from `X` to any `x_i`).

When `m < n+1` the solution is non-unique, and there are an infinite family of circumspheres. In such cases, additional constraints need to be added to the matrix `M` to give a solution.

In your case, I believe that you may be wishing to constrain `X` to lie on the common hyperplane described by the points `x`, but I'll have a bit more of a think about this...